# Can performing "Yogasanas" regularly, help increase a person's existing height?

Tags: spine, bones, physical-health, yoga

"Yogasanas" have some astonishing health benefits, but can it help in making a person taller?

I've searched and found that some "Aasanas" do actually help besides performing "Suryanamaskar" (Sun salutations)!

Here's a "[Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-yoga-asanas-to-increase-height)" QnA for the same.

Here area a few names:

- Tadasana (Tree-pose)
- Chakrasana
- Hastpadasana (Hand to foot-pose)
- Trikonasana (Triangle-pose)
- Bhujangasana (Cobra-pose)

> But what if you wish to grow taller anyway? Is there a way to increase height naturally?
>   Yes! Yoga can make you grow taller by addressing a few key issues. Essentially, yoga stretches your spine, lengthens your back and leg muscles, and improves your posture.

[Source](https://www.artofliving.org/in-en/yoga/yoga-benefits/grow-your-height-with-yoga):